# MSER full implementation in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, implementation, matlab-cvst, mser

I wanted to know if there is a full implementation of MSER ([Maximally stable extremal regions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximally_stable_extremal_regions)) in MATLAB?
The ones at [VLFeat](http://www.vlfeat.org/~vedaldi/code/mser.html) are Mex or C++ implementations and are imported to Matlab

Thanks for the guidance.

Comment: If you have to add a new tag, that's a good sign you need to explain the acronym in your question.

Comment: Well probably right you are :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about [`detectMSERFeatures`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/vision/ref/detectmserfeatures.html) in the CVS toolbox?

Comment: Does it provide the complete implementation which I can look at ?

Comment: Sorry, I don't have the newest version of Matlab, so my CVS toolbox doesn't contain this function. However, there is complete Matlab code for other functions in the toolbox (e.g. `estimateFundamentalMatrix`), so I suppose there will be a complete implementation for `detectMSERFeatures` as well.

Comment: OK, may be I need to get Matlab and check it myself. If I find the code, will mark your answer. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yeah ,[CVS toolbox](http://www.mathworks.de/products/computer-vision/) does have the complete implementation of MSER detector .Check  the *detectMSERFeatures.m* file.